# Visual Studio 2013 Solution Explorer Not Showing Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model, solution-explorer

I am trying to start a side-project to learn some MVC coding.

I am having some weird behaviour when I have reopened my MVC project.

The classes I created "Backpacker" and "Booking" are not showing up in the solution explorer. I have tried pressing the "Show all files" button, but this does not help.

As you can see in the screenshots, I have the class file open, and the path is pointing to the current project. Also you can see that my classes are in the same directory as the other classes that are visible in the models folder.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? It is hugely frustrating and I feel like maybe I have not configured something correctly?

Thanks in advance

[image: solution explorer]

[image: folder]

//EDIT//

Darn it - I tried the "Show all files" once more and this time it seemed to "almost" work... see the newest screenshot.

However Visual Studio is still obviously not connecting them to the project correctly.... does anyone know why? or how to fix/prevent this in future?

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Looks like your files are not loaded correctly . can you check if the files exist in that directory?

Comment: That second screenshot is of File Explorer from within the Model folder... so you can see the files are definitely there... alongside AccountViewModels and IdentityModels (which are both showing correctly in the solution explorer).

Comment: that screenshots means that the files are referenced in your project SwaggerMVC and does not mean they are physically located in your harddrive (it's two different things)  Here's one thing to do : right click on backpacker.cs and click on "open containing folder"

Comment: if the files physically exists on your HD you can reload them and that will fix your issue

Comment: I meant the screenshot further up which shows windows explorer... the files exist there. However I think what you are saying about the project not referencing the files might be correct. If I right click the file in solution explorer there is an option "Include in this project" (but no open containing folder option). So this looks like my project isnt referencing them.... But I don't get why not? when I created the class file I did so by right clicking the models folder and "Add new item"

Comment: For some reason your SwaggersMVC.cproj file got corrupted (millions of reasons for that) try to add the files again :> add existing item and then add them

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help Alundra, it helped me find what I had been doing wrong - I hadn't corrupted the csproj file, I was just unaware I had to save my project file to keep the references I had added. Very noob mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this problem was my own fault. I overlooked something I had done without realising what was actually happening.

When I added my new classes through solution explorer, that was all done fine. However When I closed visual studio and had the following prompt:

[image]

I clicked "no" because I usually work with XSLT which doesn't require saving the solution for my changes to be kept.

When you add references to new class files in your project, the project needs to be saved or you will lose this data (duhhh).

To fix this issue I did the following:

[image: add references]

And then made sure I SAVED THE SOLUTION changes.

Thanks for your help - hopefully this may be of use to other people.